# Network setup, SSH connection timeout with AWS and .pem

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, pem

I'm trying to log into my AWS server via SSH, it's set up with a .pem permissions file for extra security, I've added my IP to the security groups correctly, but when I try to connect, I get an operation timeout.

I thought maybe the Network settings were blocking outbound SSH, but I could connect to another server, this one didn't have any .pem file, only usual password.

I'm wondering if the network handles connections differently with a .pem file ?

The fact I can connect to SSH on this other server, I'm assuming the network outbound connection is handled differently maybe by the firewall when a permissions file is involved.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you restarted the instance - it only seems to pick up permissions if you do.

Comment: Also, if you're using ubuntu, remember it's ubuntu@ rather than root@ (both of those got me when I started on EC2)

Comment: Hi, I don't think it's to do with the permissions, because I'm not getting a permissions denied response, it's only a timeout for some reason, also I am using ubuntu as username, I can log in from the office, but I need to login from another office location, which has tighter network settings. I was wondering what outbound parameter if any would block ssh with .pem and allow standard ssh ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the output when you try the following:

```
ssh -vvv -i foobar.pem user@my-amazon-host
```

Comment: I tried, and got: *****OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0  . ***** what does it mean?